# Same position for duplicate values in a php array iterated with foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code that returns the indexed position of a value which its key matches the provided value in the parameter of the function($haystack).

```
 $results = array("098"=>90,"099"=>89,"100"=>77,"101"=>77);

function getPosition($results,$StudentID){
    arsort($results);

    $index = 1;
    $exists = '';
    $keys = array_keys($results);

    foreach($keys as $key)
    {
        if($key == $StudentID)
        {
        $score = $results[$key];
        $position = $index;
        }
        $index++;
    }
  return $position;

}
echo getPosition($results,"098").'<br />';
echo getPosition($results,"099").'<br />';
echo getPosition($results,"100").'<br />';
echo getPosition($results,"101").'<br />';
```

The results are listed below:

- 90=1
- 89=2
- 77=4
- 77=3

Now my problem is:
1. I don't know how to get the function to return same position for two similar values(eg. 77);

edit: The StudentID parameter in the function is the key for array values.
eg. 098 is a key in the array and its the value for a particular StudentID

Answer (score 0):

Simple return the positions as array.

```
$results = array("098"=>90,"099"=>89,"100"=>77,"101"=>77);

function getPosition($results,$StudentID)
{
arsort($results);

$index = 1;
$exists = '';
$keys = array_keys($results);
$position = array();

foreach($keys as $key)
{
    if($key == $StudentID)
    {
    $score = $results[$key];
    $position[] = $index;
    }
    $index++;
}
return $position;

}

print_r(getPosition($results,"77"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you be searching for values rather than keys?

```
$results = array("098"=>90,"099"=>89,"100"=>77,"101"=>77);

function getPosition($results, $StudentID) {
  $index = 1;
  $indexes = array();
  foreach ($results as $key=>$value) {
    if ($value == $StudentID) $results[] = $index;
    $index++;
  }

  return $indexes;
}

print_r(getPosition($results, "77"));
```

Comment: am actually searching for keys not values. because i return a particular position where a key in the array matches the value provided for studentid in the function

Comment: ok - i'm not 100% sure i understand the problem, but does it have something to do with the arsort rearranging the values before you search. If your problem is that 100 and 101 are swapped around, this is likely what is doing it.